# Enterprise Wiki Page - expose Categories column

Tags: development, metadata, wiki-pages, enterprise-wiki, categories

I created a new enterprise wiki site and when I created new page, the column with categories or rating is not exposed. But the categories column exist and works (every page i create have categories and I can use filter on them). So my question is. How can I expose the categories in Enterprise Wiki Page?

Basicaly, I want this: [image]

where I have this: [image]

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

currently I have an enterprise wiki page that is like what you wanted. I will describe the steps I took and hopefully it will help you.

1. Create a subsite that has an "Enterprise Wiki" template. This can be selected in the "Template Selection", under the "Publishing" tab.

   a. If the "Publishing" tab is not found, go to the main/parent site, under "Site Settings > Site Actions > Manage Site Features", activate "SharePoint Server Publishing" or "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" if you see it.

   b. If you can't activate "SharePoint Server Publishing" and can't find "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure", you will have to go to the parent site of this existing site to activate "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure".
2. Any page you add in this newly created subsite would have the layout that you are looking for.